# Is there any SMTP (business email) service for Tor?

Tags: email

I'm running a onion website and was wondering if there is any (Tor) business email service for my website so I can send out emails without revealing my server IP. Currently I have emails disabled.

Anyone knows what options I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Autistici has email reachable through a onion domain
http://www.autistici.org/en/services/mail.html

You can get a account there, then pipe mail through there, but keep in mind your server
has to be able to reach onion domains, one way of doing so is to 'torify' your server, 
(https://wiki.torproject.org/noreply/TheOnionRouter/TransparentProxy) meaning that all dns requests and such goes through Tor.

By doing so you can easily use 'sendmail' and any other way of sending email through your website.
But keep in mind any 'leaking' data that can come with the emails being sent.

By using autistici's service you can reach any email address on clearnet through Tor.

Comment: You clearly didn't read my posting. I have a hidden service page and want to send out emails without revealing my server ip. I don't want abc@aiufhiasffa.onion crap :-) Or maybe i was just unclear in my posting. Anyway - this doesnt help my case.

Comment: see here: http://autistici.org/en/stuff/man_anon/tor.html
Well, you want to send email without revealing your servers IP - and using a .onion service for sending the emails is the way to do so, or you have to torify your server and use Gmail or any other such service (which you access through tor).

If you use the service I mention above then the domain will not end with .onion when the user gets the email. I have a user@cryptolab.net for example.

Comment: Stig, when using torify this would solve the issue of my server ip being transmitted in the email headers?

Comment: The .onion service does not see your IP if you connect to it through a 'torified' OS, it would be the same as when you connect to any onion service, the onion server only sees data from 127.0.0.1 . But before deploying it you should to some proper testing to make sure it works as intended.

Also see Jens's reply on another similar topic, might be of interest to what you want to do:
http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/sending-anonymous-email

Comment: Does this torified work on any business email service? All i want is to make sure my server ip is not revealed in the HELO or similar email headers. And i want to use my domain as sender. So i want to be able to send email like usual with my business email provider, but not transmit the server IP to him or at least not in the headers.